# How to place css-grid elements into a grid container using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm doing a memory game using plain js and css-grid. I have seen solution with flex-box, but I want to do it with css-grid instead. The challenge I faced now is placing the grid elements into the grid container using javascript. I know how to do it in css but couldn't do it with js. I have tried the following so far with no luck:

```
const fillGrid = () => {
    let i = 1;
    document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item').forEach(element => {
        element.style.gridArea = `block${i++}`;
        document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(element);
    });
}

fillGrid();
```

My intention was to assign 'grid-area' properties for each grid-item in javascript while keeping the remaining properties of the css-grid in the css part. I wanted to use javascript because I want to change the position of each element dynamically.

HTML:

```
    <div class="grid-container" id="grid">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/5.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/6.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/7.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/8.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img src="img/9.jpg" class="frot-face"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'block1 block2 block3 block4' 'block5 block6 block7 block8' 'block1 block2 block3 block4' 'block5 block6 block7 block8';
    padding: 3em 2em 3em 2em;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    width: 73vmin;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: seems like setting grid area through js always outputs the shorthand value of `grid-area: value / value / value /value;`

Comment: @AbeCaymo thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve this issue. The main reason my code was not working was because I misused `gridArea` property. Unlike the CSS `grid-area` property, in JS( or DOM) this property is not used to assign names to grid items. Instead it's

> used as a shorthand property for the grid-row-start,
>   grid-column-start, grid-row-end and the grid-column-end properties

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp or https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/grid-area.html.
My final code looks like:

```
const fillGrid = () => {
    let col = 1, row = 1;
    const items = [...document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item')];
    const grid = document.getElementById('grid');
    items.forEach(item => {
        item.style.gridArea = `${row} / ${col}`;
        col++;
        if(col>4){
          col=1;
          row++;
        }
    });
}

fillGrid();
```

CSS:

```
 .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;

    padding: 3em 2em 3em 2em;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    width: 73vmin;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```